# Error while creating pivot table: "Application Defined or object Defined Error."

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating a pivot table. I have three sheets and I am creating the pivot table in sheet `CAT_Pivot` with data in a preparation sheet.

I am able to achieve my target, but I get a runtime error at the end of the execution. The runtime error states

> Application Defined or object Defined Error.

To add to that, how do I calculate the values in the pivot table? I used `.function = xlcount`  and I didn't succeed.

Here is my code:

```
Sub AutoPivot()

Dim PvtCache            As PivotCache
Dim PvtTbl              As PivotTable
Dim PvtSht              As Worksheet

' set Pivot Cache for Pivot Table
' Your range is static, there are ways to refer to a dynamic range
Set PvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="Preparation sheet!R1C1:R1048576C8")

' set the Pivot table's sheet
Set PvtSht = Worksheets("CAT_Pivot")

' add this line in case the Pivot table doesn't exit >> first time running this Macro
On Error Resume Next
Set PvtTbl = PvtSht.PivotTables("PivotTable1") ' check if "PivotTable7" Pivot Table already created (in past runs of this Macro)

On Error GoTo 0
If PvtTbl Is Nothing Then ' Pivot table object is nothing >> create it

    ' create a new Pivot Table in "PivotTable4" sheet
    Set PvtTbl = PvtSht.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PvtCache, TableDestination:=PvtSht.Range("A3"), TableName:="PivotTable1")

    With PvtTbl
        With .PivotFields("Category")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 1
        End With
        With .PivotFields("Colour")
            .Orientation = xlColumnField
            .Position = 1
        End With
        With .PivotFields("Category")
            .PivotItems("DG-035583").Visible = False
            .PivotItems("DG-048917").Visible = False
            .PivotItems("DG-Series").Visible = False
            .PivotItems("gn").Visible = False
            .PivotItems("yl").Visible = False
            .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
        End With
        With .PivotFields("Colour")
            .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
        End With

    End With
Else
    ' just refresh the Pivot cache with the updated Range
    PvtTbl.ChangePivotCache PvtCache
    PvtTbl.RefreshTable
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to write *nested with statements*. Try to rewrite your code from scratch without using more than one `with` at a time.

E.g., this part is bad:

```
With PvtTbl
    With .PivotFields("Category")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With .PivotFields("Colour")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With .PivotFields("Category")
        .PivotItems("DG-035583").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("DG-048917").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("DG-Series").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("gn").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("yl").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
    End With
    With .PivotFields("Colour")
        .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
    End With

End With
```

You may rewrite it like this:

```
With PvtTbl.PivotFields("Category")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
With PvtTbl.PivotFields("Colour")
    .Orientation = xlColumnField
    .Position = 1
End With
```

Reference for *nested if* - [Nested With Statement hiearchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41815258/nested-with-statement-hiearchy)

Cheers!

***Edit:*** Actually nested if is not that bad, it even works. But still, its a bit confusing.

Comment: Thank you. I will rewrite it and  try.

Comment: @Mikz - also, try to build a smaller model of your problem and post it if you still experience it. E.g., just a few `PivotItems` and `PivotFields`.

Comment: I tried the way you suggested, the error still exists.

Comment: @Mikz - on which line do you get it exactly? Add the info to the question.

Comment: means you Need an snapshot of my Pivot table ?

Comment: @Mikz - means that you get a yellow line in the VB Editor when you get the error. Where is this line?

Comment: @Vityanta I tried it in each line. It doesnt Point the error any where in the code. But when i run it as whole, then i get that error

Comment: @Mikz - have you tried this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23883640/pivots-and-run-time-error-1004-application-defined-or-object-defined-error

Comment: I will go through that and get back to you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147158/discussion-between-mikz-and-vityata).